# iphone is there a way to have the image in a button flip over?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a guessing game, where you clcik on a card and it turns over.  You then try to find the matching card.

I made programs before that would flip a image over from one picture to another.  But I can't figure out how this could be done on the image of a button.  I saw a game that seems to do this.  You click a button and the image flips over from one image to another.

Don't know how hey do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same way you flip an image, `UIButton` inherits from `UIView`, as does `UIImage`. Simply make an animation and use the `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` or some other option.